# PHP IDE: with SFTP alternative

Tags: sftp, phpstorm, phpdesigner

Title: Developing on filesystem's server.

Gonna explain my situation:
At job i use phpstorm in linux (because of the shortcuts that let me work fast), i have a folder mounted with fuse, so i can write code in the server as a 'local' folder.
My workmates use phpdesigner in windows, so they can make a sftp conection and work the same way as i do. (i know, that's not a proper way to work but the whole team don't know other way so i have to do the same as they)
But now i have to work at home, and i have tried to work with phpstorm, but i can't mount a sftp connection as phpdesigner do
and my home-pc use windows, so i can't mount a remote filesystem as with linux(and i don't want to).
So i tried phpdesigner (and make a sftp connection) but, i work very slow.. phpstorm have a lot of shortcuts (and i need that shortcuts), phpdesigner doesn't has that (and i've finding shortcuts).. 
Here is the question:
Does someone know an IDE that let me write code in server (like phpdesigner with sftp connection) and decent shortcuts? and works in windows (no depending on other softwares)?

By the way. I don't need answers like "install a software that map a sftp conection to a drive in windows, and work with phpstorm as 'local'". I'm finding an IDE that do all the job.
Only if there's no other way, then welcome any suggestion! (:

Comment: Aptana Studio 3 is the only I can think of more complete than PHPStorm.

Comment: thanks man! :D that's what i need!! thank you, i'm gonna test it!

Answer (score 2):

PhpStorm has deployment option to work with FTP/SFTP/FTPS (File | New project from the existing files). See tutorials: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm .